# Tkinter - can't get .get() working in other class

Tags: python, tkinter

I hope you can help, I'm doing my best to learn tkinter Python, but I'm stuck.
I first created the app with placing the login screen to root and the open an `Toplevel` window. But after that I think that's not the correct way to work.

So I'm trying to change it completely and put it all in classes, but I keep getting an error on line 195

```
error: AttributeError: 'Pageone' object has no attribute 'usernamelabelent'
```

which is in `class Pageone(tk.Frame):`.

```
from cProfile import label
from calendar import c
from cgitb import text
from logging import PlaceHolder
from textwrap import fill
import tkinter
from tkinter import font
from turtle import Screen, color
from setuptools import command
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox
import secrets
import sqlite3
from tkinter.font import BOLD, Font
import tkinter as tk
from configparser import ConfigParser


class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self._frame = None
        self.switch_frame(Pageone)

    def switch_frame(self, frame_class):
        """Destroys current frame and replaces it with a new one."""
        new_frame = frame_class(self)
        if self._frame is not None:
            self._frame.destroy()
        self._frame = new_frame
        self._frame.grid()

class loginscreen(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.master.title("loginscreen")
        bgcolor = '#232f34'
        bgcolor2 = '#344955'
        bgcolor3 = '#ffffff'
        self.master.configure(background=bgcolor)
        self.master.geometry("300x500")
        myfont = Font(family="Verdana", size=10, weight=BOLD)
        myfont2 = Font(family="Helvetica", size=26, weight=BOLD)
        myfont3 = Font(family="Helvetica", size=10)
        myfont4 = Font(family="Arial", size=7, weight=BOLD)
        def noaccountpage():
            global search_entry, search, us_entry, pw_entry

            messagebtn2 = Label(search, text = "Please fill in your details below", background=bgcolor, fg=bgcolor3, font=myfont4)
            messagebtn2.grid(row=2,column=0, columnspan=2, padx=10)

            uspwframe2 = LabelFrame(search,background=bgcolor2, bd=0,)
            uspwframe2.grid(padx=10, pady=10)

            vvv = StringVar()
            vvvv = StringVar()

            us_entry = tk.Entry(uspwframe2, width=34, font=myfont3, textvariable=vvv)
            us_entry.insert(0, "Enter Your Username")
            us_entry.bind("<Button-1>")
            us_entry.bind("<KeyRelease>")
            us_entry.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=10, pady=10)

            pw_entry = tk.Entry(uspwframe2,width=34, font=myfont3, textvariable=vvvv,show="*")
            pw_entry.insert(0, "Password")
            pw_entry.bind("<Button-1>")
            pw_entry.bind("<KeyRelease>")
            pw_entry.grid(row=4, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=10, pady=10)

            loginbtn = Button(uspwframe2, text="Create", command = tk.noaccountcreate, bg="black",fg='white',font=myfont, bd=0, width=10)
            loginbtn.grid(row=5, column=0,padx=2)


        def login2():
        
            #getting form data
            uname = usernamelabelent.get()
            pwd = passwordlabelent.get()
            #applying empty validation
            if uname=='' or pwd=='':
                self.messagebtn.config(text = "These fields can't be Empty")
            else:
            #open database
                conn = sqlite3.connect('uspw.db')
            #select query
                cursor = conn.execute('SELECT * from ADMIN where USERNAME="%s" and PASSWORD="%s"'%(uname,pwd))
            #fetch data 
                if cursor.fetchone():
                    self.messagebtn.config(text = "Login Succes")
                    command=lambda: master.switch_frame(Pageone())
                else:
                    self.messagebtn.config(text = "Wrong Username or Password")

            # add new record to database
        def noaccountcreate():
            global us_entry,pw_entry,tkinter,username, strip

            
            # Update the database
            # Create a database or connect to one that exists
            conn = sqlite3.connect('uspw.db')

            # Create a cursor instance
            c = conn.cursor()

            # Add New Record
            c.execute("INSERT INTO ACTIVATE(USERNAME,PASSWORD) VALUES (:username, :password)",
                {
                    'username': us_entry.get(),
                    'password': pw_entry.get(),
                })


            # Commit changes
            conn.commit()

            # Close our connection
            conn.close()
                
            us_entry.delete(0, END)
            pw_entry.delete(0, END)

        def on_clickus(event):

            event.widget.delete(0, tk.END)
        def on_clickpw(event):

            event.widget.delete(0, tk.END)
        def caps(event):
            v.set(v.get().lower())
        def caps2(event):
            vv.set(vv.get().lower())
        self.img = PhotoImage(file='key.png')
        Label(self,image=self.img, background=bgcolor).grid(padx=20,row=0, pady=25, column=0, columnspan=2)


        mytext = "Please fill in your details below"

        self.welcomelabel = Label(self,text = "Welcome!", background=bgcolor, fg=bgcolor3, font=myfont2)
        self.welcomelabel.grid(row=1,column=0, columnspan=2, padx=10)
        self.messagebtn = Label(self,text = "Please fill in your details below", background=bgcolor, fg=bgcolor3, font=myfont4)
        self.messagebtn.grid(row=2,column=0, columnspan=2, padx=10)

        self.uspwframe = LabelFrame(self,background=bgcolor2, bd=0,)
        self.uspwframe.grid(padx=10, pady=10)

        v = StringVar()
        vv = StringVar()

        usernamelabelent = tk.Entry(self.uspwframe, width=34, font=myfont3, textvariable=v)
        usernamelabelent.insert(0, "Enter Your Username")
        usernamelabelent.bind("<Button-1>", on_clickus)
        usernamelabelent.bind("<KeyRelease>", caps)
        usernamelabelent.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=10, pady=10)

        passwordlabelent = tk.Entry(self.uspwframe,width=34, font=myfont3, textvariable=vv,show="*")
        passwordlabelent.insert(0, "Password")
        passwordlabelent.bind("<Button-1>", on_clickpw)
        passwordlabelent.bind("<KeyRelease>", caps2)
        passwordlabelent.grid(row=4, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=10, pady=10)

        loginbtn = Button(self.uspwframe, text="LOGIN", command = login2, bg="black",fg='white',font=myfont, bd=0, width=10)
        loginbtn.grid(row=5, column=0,padx=2)

        #messagebtn = Label(uspwframe, text=" ", background=bgcolor2, fg=bgcolor3, font=myfont)
        #messagebtn.grid(row=7, columnspan=2)

        self.noaccount = Button(self.uspwframe, text="NEW LOGIN", command = noaccountpage, bg="black",fg='white',font=myfont, bd=0, width=10)
        self.noaccount.grid(row=5, column=1, padx=2)

        self.noaccount = Button(self.uspwframe, text="ACCOUNT FORGOTTEN", command = noaccountpage, bg="black",fg='white',font=myfont, bd=0, width=20)
        self.noaccount.grid(row=6, columnspan=2, padx=2, pady= 7)


class Pageone(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
    
        global search_entry, search
        self.master = master
        self.master.title("loginscreen")
        bgcolor = '#232f34'
        bgcolor2 = '#344955'
        bgcolor3 = '#ffffff'
        myfont = Font(family="Verdana", size=10, weight=BOLD)
        myfont2 = Font(family="Helvetica", size=26, weight=BOLD)
        myfont3 = Font(family="Helvetica", size=10)
        myfont4 = Font(family="Arial", size=7, weight=BOLD)



        admin = "sil"
        if str(self.master.usernamelabelent.get(loginscreen)) == admin:
            my_menu = Menu(search)
            search.config(menu=my_menu)
            # Configure our menu
            option_menu = Menu(my_menu, tearoff=0)
            my_menu.add_cascade(label="Options", menu=option_menu)
            # Drop down menu
            option_menu.add_command(label="Info")
            option_menu.add_command(label="Admin")
            option_menu.add_separator()
            option_menu.add_command(label="Exit", command=tk.quit)
        else:
            my_menu = Menu(tk)
            search.config(menu=my_menu)
            # Configure our menu
            option_menu = Menu(my_menu, tearoff=0)
            my_menu.add_cascade(label="Options", menu=option_menu)
            # Drop down menu
            option_menu.add_command(label="Info")
            option_menu.add_separator()
            option_menu.add_command(label="Exit", command=search.quit)
    
            welcomeframe = Frame(Pageone,bg=bgcolor3, bd=0, width=700)
            welcomeframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=tkinter.E + tkinter.W)

            namelabel = Label(welcomeframe, font = myfont4, text="Welcome " + str(self.master.usernamelabelent.get(loginscreen)) )
            namelabel.grid(padx=20, pady=20)

            # Add entry box
            search_entry = Entry(Pageone, font=("Helvetica", 18))
            search_entry.grid(pady=20, padx=20)

            # Add button
            search_button = Button(Pageone, text="Search Records")
            search_button.grid(padx=20, pady=20)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SampleApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. This is far too much code to expect others to go through for this problem. Please try to remove functionality that is not relevant to causing the problem.

Comment: Actually all of it seems relevant because need to trace through where each class is instantiated from.  Thanks for not down voting this

Comment: @InhirCode the amount of code in each class could be severely reduced while still producing the same error. This is in fact what a [mre] is

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: stackoverflow doesn't show which line is `195`

Comment: you have to use `self.` to access variables outside class. And use `self.` to access variables in other methods in the same class. And then you can stop using `global`

Comment: you should use `Button(self,...)` instead of `Button(Pageone, ...)`. And stop nesting all functions inside `__init__` - it makes code unreadable.

Comment: I got different exception: `AttributeError: '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'usernamelabelent'` on the line `if str(self.master.usernamelabelent.get(loginscreen)) == admin:` inside `Pageone` class.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest to attach `usernamelabelent` and probably `passwordlabelent` in `class loginscreen` to `self` ie
`self.usernamelabelent =`

`self.master.usernamelabelent.get(loginscreen)` is confused. Suggest assign `loginscreen` separately to a variable before doing this part to access `usernamelabelent` through the variable. `usernamelabelent` is an attribute of `loginscreen` if attached to `self` in that class.
An `<entry>.get()` doesn't have any argument - it returns the whole entry string.

Maybe split this statement into separate steps that show what you are intending to happen.